# Embedding some third party subclass with all fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Assume we have a `Parent` class in some library:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Also assume that we have a `Child` class in some other library:

```
public class Child extends Parent {

}
```

I want to use Child class as embedded in one of my entities, like

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    // id and other fields
    @Embedded
    private Child child;

    // getters, setters etc.
}
```

The problem is, the fields defined in `Parent` are not embedded, i.e. there are no columns for them in the corresponding table of `SomeEntity`.

Just to make sure that it is because of inheritance, I first added some fields to `Child` and observed that they are embedded as expected. I also tried embedding Parent directly, and the columns for them are generated this time too.

The problem is, how can I embed the fields defined in a super class?

I tried to mark `child` field of `SomeEntity` with `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)`, but it did not work. I also tried to change those fields in `Parent` class (i.e. `name` in our example) to public but this didn't work either.

In case it is related, my project is a `Spring Boot` project, with `Hibernate` as the `JPA` provider. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** The attempted `orm.xml` file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
                 version="2.0">

    <embeddable class="...Child" access="PROPERTY">
        <attributes>
            <basic name="name">
                <column nullable="false"/>
            </basic>
        </attributes>
    </embeddable>
</entity-mappings>
```

I tried with `access="FIELD"` and also without any `access` parameter, but no luck.

To make sure that `orm.xml` is loaded, I gave an invalid `class` to `embeddable` and observed `ClassNotFoundException`, hence it is loaded.

Comment: Is your `Child` class annotated with `@Embeddable` ?

Comment: or do you have an `orm.xml` for the third party class defining it as `<embeddable>` ? (and that way you don't have to edit the actual class to add annotations).

Comment: @LuayAbdulraheem no it's not, because it's in some other library.

Comment: @NeilStockton If I try to embed `Parent` without `orm.xml`, it works. So I thought it is not mandatory. However, I tried with `orm.xml` too but it didn't work again.

Comment: You use `orm.xml` when you don't want/have annotations, or when you want to override annotations. Since you don't share with us whether you have annotations (on the third party class) then people have to guess. Any JPA provider that is compliant supports `orm.xml`

Comment: @NeilStockton I have already shared my third party classes: `Parent` and `Child`. They do not have annotations, so I have to go with `orm.xml`.

Comment: so go with it ... placed under `META-INF`. As said, all compliant JPA providers support it. http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/metadata_xml.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Embeddables),

> The JPA spec does not support embeddable objects having inheritance, although some JPA providers may allow this.

I guess this as the cause of my problem. Shame on JPA.

In an answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278249/hibernate-embeddable-class-which-extends-another-embeddable-class-properties), it is stated that:

> Hibernate doesn't support inheritance of @Embeddable component.

Comment: although some/most JPA providers do support a form of it